# BF2 via CrossOver "@" problem

Tags: macos, windows, wine

I've installed BF2 with CrossOver, and so far it's working.
Now I like to play online but I can't login with my e-mail because of the "@"

Does anyone know how to type the "@"?
Can't find it...

***Thanks***

Comment: How do you normally type "@" and what happens when you try that?

Comment: Does it prevent you from typing it in, or what?

Comment: On Mac I normaly type ALT+L but nothing happened so I tried @ on Windows -> nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually depends on your keyboard. It's <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> on US keyboards, and I suspect you might have to use that in Crossover as well.

Also keep in mind that Crossover has the ability to [configure your modifier keys](http://www.codeweavers.com/support/docs/crossover-mac/mac-preferences-keyboard), so you might want to try some other modifiers with <kbd>L</kbd> if that's what you normally do.

Comment: Thanks that worked. ALT+L don't work because I'm form Germany ;)